# Tomcat 6 configuration for standalone server

Tags: tomcat6

I have the web app that works one my tomcat 6 (local) on Windows. I have bouhgt dedicated server and installed on it tomcat 6. Ubuntu is installed on server. Now if I try to enter my webapps http:\{ipaddress}{web-app} the browser opens title web page. Then appears dialog window for entering log name and password. But on pressing button login browser Chrome is saying that on accessing servlet {servletname} server returns Status Code:500 Internal Server Error.
How should I configure tomcat6 for Internet? I think that catalina doesnt return answer from servlet for outside request.
I want to use tomcat6 as standalone server.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear dude! i have tomcat 7 configured and accessible from internet since i have valid IP on my server. try to take a look at tomcat log (usually at /var/log/tomcat6(or 7)/...